# Understanding faces of an object files

Tags: 3d, vertices

I downloaded an object files with vertices in below format
`v 10.7732 58.0762 288.7190`
then faces in the below format
`f 2618/3145/721 2646/3174/721 2683/3219/721 2619/3146/721`
Now, i;m confused on how the face format works, will someone interpret this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- Each vertex has a vector which is indexed `i=1..n` and it defined by

  ```
  v X Y Z
  ```

  where each `X`, `Y`, `Z` are the real coordinates of the vertex.
- Similarly with normal vectors

  ```
  vn X Y Z
  ```
- And with texture vectors (2 coordinates)

  ```
  vt X Y
  ```
- And with parameter vectors (? coordinates)

  ```
  vp X ...
  ```
- Each face has 4 triplets of indexes

  - `V` is the three vertexes of the face defining a triangle, using the vector index. So `1/2/3` defines a triangle with coordinates `v(1)`, `v(2)` and `v(3)`.
  - `VT` for each vertex of the face this is the texture vector. So `1/2/3` defines three vectors `vt(1)`, `vt(2)` and `vt(3)`.
  - `VN` for each vertex of the face this is the vertex normal. So `1/2/3` defines three vectors `vn(1)`, `vn(2)` and `vn(3)`.
  - `VP` for each vertex of the face this is the parameter vector. So `1/2/3` defines three vectors `vp(1)`, `vp(2)` and `vp(3)`.

References:

- http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/
- http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec